# How can I get to nmake in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have installed the Professional version - but with the new Windows 8 start menu I can't find the VS2012 Command Prompt for the life of me. Any thoughts on where this might be? I'm trying to compile a C++ library for WinRT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at the "Start" screen, you can type "visual studio command prompt" but you must remember to select "Apps" while searching for it.

hopes this help.

Comment: that true but you might end up with more than 5 results

Comment: All mine are called VS2012, so searching for Visual Studio doesn't give the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the command prompt by executing
"\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_arm